# Optional NPM dependency installation

Tags: typescript, npm, npm-install

We have a shared library where it installed all the bootstraping code for us. Most people use raw Javascript for their front end but a few people also use Typescript.

Is it possible for the package.json to also include a list of dependencies that are for Typescript only (like all the `@types` and other Typescript related modules) that only get installed if you provide a certain flag? i.e. running `npm install` would only install the "normal" packages but `npm install --some-flag` would install the additional packages as well.

Comment: How would the user express this in **their** package.json?

Comment: That's what I'm asking. Is that at all possible? Maybe something like `additionalDependencies`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps what you're looking for is a combined usage of optionalDependencies and the --no-optional flag.

From https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json :

> **optionalDependencies**
>
> If a dependency can be used, but you would like npm to proceed if it
>   cannot be found or fails to install, then you may put it in the
>   optionalDependencies object. This is a map of package name to version
>   or url, just like the dependencies object. The difference is that
>   build failures do not cause installation to fail.
>
> It is still your program's responsibility to handle the lack of the
>   dependency. For example, something like this:
>
> ```
> try {
>   var foo = require('foo')
>   var fooVersion = require('foo/package.json').version
> } catch (er) {
>   foo = null
> }
> if ( notGoodFooVersion(fooVersion) ) {
>   foo = null
> }
>
> // .. then later in your program ..
>
> if (foo) {
>   foo.doFooThings()
> }
> ```
>
> Entries in optionalDependencies will override entries of the same name
>   in dependencies, so it's usually best to only put in one place.

And from https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install :

> The **--no-optional** argument will prevent optional dependencies from
>   being installed.

Comment: Is there a reverse of that? I want the default behavior to NOT install optional, and only install optionals if I provide the flag

Comment: I am not aware of such a thing. If it's of such importance, then why not write a script that does so?